# Equivalence of two norms

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

Define two norms as following: $$
\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{1}={ \max_{0\leq x\leq1}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|}
  , \quad\text{ and }\quad \left\Vert f\right\Vert _{2}={\intop_{0}^{1}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|dx} 
$$

on the vector space $ C\left[0,1\right] $ (the continuous functions).

I need to prove that the two norms aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x):=\max\{1-nx,0\}$, which is a continuous function for all $n$. The function $f_n$ is non-negative and reaches its maximum at $x=0$ hence $\lVert f_n\rVert_1=1$. However, the computation of the $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$-norm leads to the computation of the area of a triangle, which is half of that of a rectangle having corners $(0,0)$ and $(1/n,1)$, hence $\lVert f_n\rVert_2=1/(2n)$.

This shows that there does not exist a constant $C$ such that for each $f\in C[0,1]$, $\lVert f\rVert_1\leqslant C\lVert f\rVert_2$.

Comment: Diverge to infinity.

Comment: @MarekKryspin Thanks for the catch. I rewrote completely this answer.

Comment: +1. $\phantom{}$